# Pandas Vectorized lookup of Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This seems like it should be a common use case but I'm not finding any good guidance on this. I have a solution that works but I would rather have a vectorized lookup rather than using the Pandas `apply()` function.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd


example_dict = {
        "category1":{
                "field1": 0.0,
                "filed2": 5.0},
        "category2":{
                "field1": 5.0,
                "field2": 8.0}}

d = {"ids": range(10),
     "category": ["category1" if x % 2 == 0 else "category2" for x in range(10)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# The operation I am trying to vectorize
df['category_data'] = df.apply(lambda row: example_dict[row['category']], axis=1)
```

On the last line you can see where I am using the `apply()` function to perform the dictionary lookup. My gut tells me there should be a way to vectorize this. I may be wrong, but I would like to  know that as well. I often run into scenarios where I need to lookup information in a dictionary and add it as a column the a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Note that to get the best performance out of Pandas, generally speaking you'll want to avoid storing Python dicts in the DataFrame. Use only native (NumPy) data types such as int64s, float64s, or strings. So instead of one `category_data` column, you might be better off with `field1` and `field2` columns which each store floats. This could have significant performance benefits if you need to, say, select rows based on values from the dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using `map`

```
df['map']=df.category.map(example_dict)
df
Out[839]: 
    category  ids                   category_data  \
0  category1    0  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}   
1  category2    1  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}   
2  category1    2  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}   
3  category2    3  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}   
4  category1    4  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}   
5  category2    5  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}   
6  category1    6  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}   
7  category2    7  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}   
8  category1    8  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}   
9  category2    9  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}   
                              map  
0  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}  
1  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}  
2  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}  
3  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}  
4  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}  
5  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}  
6  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}  
7  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}  
8  {'field1': 0.0, 'filed2': 5.0}  
9  {'field1': 5.0, 'field2': 8.0}
```

If you need them into different columns

```
pd.DataFrame(df['map'].tolist())
Out[843]: 
   field1  field2  filed2
0     0.0     NaN     5.0
1     5.0     8.0     NaN
2     0.0     NaN     5.0
3     5.0     8.0     NaN
4     0.0     NaN     5.0
5     5.0     8.0     NaN
6     0.0     NaN     5.0
7     5.0     8.0     NaN
8     0.0     NaN     5.0
9     5.0     8.0     NaN
```

Or

```
df['map'].apply(pd.Series)
Out[844]: 
   field1  field2  filed2
0     0.0     NaN     5.0
1     5.0     8.0     NaN
2     0.0     NaN     5.0
3     5.0     8.0     NaN
4     0.0     NaN     5.0
5     5.0     8.0     NaN
6     0.0     NaN     5.0
7     5.0     8.0     NaN
8     0.0     NaN     5.0
9     5.0     8.0     NaN
```

Comment: I recommend not using the dot notation series indexing. On the offhand chance you name your column something like "map".

Comment: Is there a way to get the behavior of 


    df.apply(lambda row: example_dict.get(row['category'], pd.np.NaN), axis=1)

Comment: hm... you sure this is vectorized? I've tried map, lambda, and `df['id'].apply(function))` and all methods seem to have similar times measured by magic command in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 3):

You could create a second DataFrame from `example_dict` and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two Dataframes

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(example_dict.keys(),columns=
             ['category']).assign(category_data=example_dict.values())

df.merge(d2,on='category',how='left')

    category  ids                     category_data
0  category1    0  {u'filed2': 5.0, u'field1': 0.0}
1  category2    1  {u'field2': 8.0, u'field1': 5.0}
2  category1    2  {u'filed2': 5.0, u'field1': 0.0}
3  category2    3  {u'field2': 8.0, u'field1': 5.0}
4  category1    4  {u'filed2': 5.0, u'field1': 0.0}
5  category2    5  {u'field2': 8.0, u'field1': 5.0}
6  category1    6  {u'filed2': 5.0, u'field1': 0.0}
7  category2    7  {u'field2': 8.0, u'field1': 5.0}
8  category1    8  {u'filed2': 5.0, u'field1': 0.0}
9  category2    9  {u'field2': 8.0, u'field1': 5.0}
```

---

Separating Dictionary values to columns

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(example_dict).T
df.merge(d2,how='left',left_on='category',right_index=True)

    category  ids  field1  field2  filed2
0  category1    0     0.0     NaN     5.0
1  category2    1     5.0     8.0     NaN
2  category1    2     0.0     NaN     5.0
3  category2    3     5.0     8.0     NaN
4  category1    4     0.0     NaN     5.0
5  category2    5     5.0     8.0     NaN
6  category1    6     0.0     NaN     5.0
7  category2    7     5.0     8.0     NaN
8  category1    8     0.0     NaN     5.0
9  category2    9     5.0     8.0     NaN
```